# Phonegap displaying stored data on local storage gives error

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I am new to Phonegap, since it uses web technologies to code mobile apps, i preferred using phonegap over native java coding just for the sake of making UI easy.
in this the geolocation shows CAUGHT SECURITY EXCEPTIONS, i dont know from where this emerges.
kindly help..

Start Tracking Location

```
$("#startTracking_start").live('click', function(){

    // Start tracking the User
    watch_id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(

        // Success
        function(position){
            tracking_data.push(position);
        },

        // Error
        function(error){
            console.log(error);
        },

        // Settings
        { frequency: 3000, enableHighAccuracy: true });

    // Tidy up the UI
    track_id = $("#track_id").val();

    $("#track_id").hide();

    $("#startTracking_status").html("Tracking workout: <strong>" + track_id + "</strong>");
});
```

Stop Tracking Location

```
$("#startTracking_stop").live('click', function(){

    // Stop tracking the user
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watch_id);

    // Save the tracking data
    window.localStorage.setItem(track_id, JSON.stringify(tracking_data));

    // Reset watch_id and tracking_data 
    var watch_id = null;
    var tracking_data = null;

    // Tidy up the UI
    $("#track_id").val("").show();

    $("#startTracking_status").html("Stopped tracking workout: <strong>" + track_id + "</strong>");

});
```

Tracking info page

```
<div data-role="page" id="track_info">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Viewing Single route</h1>

        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home" data-transition="none" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#startTracking" data-transition="none" data-icon="plus">Track route</a></li>
                <li><a href="#history" data-transition="none" data-icon="star">History</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p id="track_info_info"></p>

        <div id="map_canvas" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;height:300px;"></div>

    </div>


</div>
```

Track info Function - When the user views the Track Info page..!!

```
$('#track_info').live('pageshow', function(){

    // Find the track_id of the workout they are viewing
    var key = $(this).attr("track_id");

    // Update the Track Info page header to the track_id
    $("#track_info div[data-role=header] h1").text(key);

    // Get all the GPS data for the specific workout
    var data = window.localStorage.getItem(key);

    // Turn the stringified GPS data back into a JS object
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    // Calculate the total distance travelled
    total_km = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

        if(i == (data.length - 1)){
            break;
        }

        total_km += gps_distance(data[i].coords.latitude, data[i].coords.longitude, data[i+1].coords.latitude, data[i+1].coords.longitude);
    }

    total_km_rounded = total_km.toFixed(2);

    // Calculate the total time taken for the track
    start_time = new Date(data[0].timestamp).getTime();
    end_time = new Date(data[data.length-1].timestamp).getTime();


    total_time_ms = end_time - start_time;
    total_time_s = total_time_ms / 1000;

    final_time_m = Math.floor(total_time_s / 60);
    final_time_s = total_time_s - (final_time_m * 60);

    // Display total distance and time
    $("#track_info_info").html('Started at <strong>'+ start_time +'</strong> and travelled <strong>' + total_km_rounded + '</strong> km in <strong>' + final_time_m + 'm</strong> and <strong>' + final_time_s + 's</strong>');

    // Set the initial Lat and Long of the Google Map
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[0].coords.latitude, data[0].coords.longitude);

    // Google Map options
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // Create the Google Map, set options
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var trackCoords = [];

    // Add each GPS entry to an array
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        trackCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].coords.latitude, data[i].coords.longitude));
    }

    // Plot the GPS entries as a line on the Google Map
    var trackPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: trackCoords,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

    // Apply the line to the map
    trackPath.setMap(map);


});
```

Log_Cat

```
    07-29 23:52:56.896: E/chromium(6931): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:190: [0729/235256:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(190)] StatHub::Init - App com.a_man.trackme isn't supported.
    07-29 23:52:56.896: E/chromium(6931): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:190: [0729/235256:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(190)] StatHub::Init - App com.a_man.trackme isn't supported.
    07-29 23:53:33.032: E/geolocationService(6931): Caught security exception registering for location updates from system. This should only happen in DumpRenderTree.
    07-29 23:53:47.015: E/geolocationService(6931): Caught security exception registering for location updates from system. This should only happen in DumpRenderTree.
    07-29 23:53:49.828: E/geolocationService(6931): Caught security exception registering for location updates from system. This should only happen in DumpRenderTree.

07-29 23:53:59.758: E/Web Console(6931): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u at file:///android_asset/www/index.html#track_info:1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot to add the right permissions to your application:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Those are needed regardless of whether you're using native APIs or HTML5 APIs for accessing the user's location.

Comment: thank you @Glorfindel adding permissions solved the geolocationService problem.. but still when locationTracking stops it saves the data on localStorage and i try to view that.. logCat shows this error messege
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u at file:///android_asset/www/index.html#track_info:1

Comment: Hard to say. I'd suggest trying to remove some parts of the code to detect the exact source of the problem.